# Python thread exit code

Tags: python, multithreading, exit-code

Is there a way to tell if a thread has exited normally or because of an exception?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned, a wrapper around the Thread class could catch that state.  Here's an example.

```
>>> from threading import Thread
>>> class MyThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        try:
            Thread.run(self)
        except Exception as err:
            self.err = err
            pass # or raise err
        else:
            self.err = None


>>> mt = MyThread(target=divmod, args=(3, 2))
>>> mt.start()
>>> mt.join()
>>> mt.err
>>> mt = MyThread(target=divmod, args=(3, 0))
>>> mt.start()
>>> mt.join()
>>> mt.err
ZeroDivisionError('integer division or modulo by zero',)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set some global variable to 0 if success, or non-zero if there was an exception. This is a pretty standard convention.

However, you'll need to protect this variable with a mutex or semaphore. Or you could make sure that only one thread will ever write to it and all others would just read it.

Comment: 0 for success may be a pretty standard convention, but wouldn't a boolean `succeded` be a little easier on the meat interpreter?

Comment: It doesn't have to be global if I subclass Thread, just need a member variable in that to indicate success. I was just wondering if there is any builtin way to do this, like the process exit code.

Comment: Threads and global state.  Two great tastes tthat tate gsrat eogetherrrrrrrrrrrrrrr Segmentation fault, core dumped.

Comment: @Glyph note how I mentioned mutexs and semaphores though.

Answer (score 0):

Have your thread function catch exceptions.  (You can do this with a simple wrapper function that just calls the old thread function inside a `try`...`except` or `try`...`except`...`else` block).  Then the question just becomes "how to pass information from one thread to another", and I guess you already know how to do that.